# Protractor. How to restart browser between tests?

Tags: protractor

I wrote a pack of tests and separately each of them works correctly (for each test I created separate file - it important for my case) , but when I try to run them all together I have some problems:
At the first I tried to restart browser after each test with `“restartBrowserBetweenTests: true”` option but as a result I receive next error:

> Failed: This driver instance does not have a valid session ID (did you
> call WebDriver.quit()?) and may no longer be used.

I read some advice for this situation, but nothing helped me.

Basically, I can get without restarting browser but in this case I want to close all active tabs after each test and I also don’t know ho to do it. With the help of this function:

```
browser.getAllWindowHandles().then((handles) => {
    browser.driver.switchTo().window(handles[1]);
    browser.driver.close();
    browser.driver.switchTo().window(handles[0]);
});
```

I can close active tab and return for the previous but the function works only if I  place this code in the test spec, that's not comfortable for me (copy it for each test) and if I call it from special file with functions it works incorrectly due to the

> “Failed: no such window: target window already closed
> from unknown error: web view not found”

errors (a consequence of a lost context).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.restart

use instead:

```
browser.restart()
```

also try to use await

```
  it('Test Puppeteer screenshot', async function()  {
    await browser.get('https://www.google.com')
    let current = await browser.getWindowHandle()
    await browser.executeScript("window.open('https://www.indiatoday.com')")
    handles = await browser.getAllWindowHandles()
    await browser.switchTo().window(handles[1]);
    await browser.close();
    await browser.switchTo().window(handles[0]);
  });
```

Note if you are using page object the nyou have to reinitialize modules:

if you are using javascript object notation for page then

https://www.npmjs.com/package/decache

```
const decache = require('decache');
 let stage1 = require('../pageobjects/stage1.js');

beforeEach(async function () {
    decache('../pageobjects/stage1.js');
    stage1 = require('../pageobjects/stage1.js');
    elements = stage1.elements;

  });
```

If you are using nodejs class:

```
let stage1 = require('../pageobjects/stage1.js');

beforeEach(async function () {
    stage1 = new PageObjects.stage1();

  });
```

This because the reference for elements have changed you have to reinitialize them